# Is there a way to apply a color profile system-wide?

Tags: gnome, color-management

I've calibrated two displays and like to apply those color profiles system-wide.

This should also include the `lightdm` user, as the switch to my user's color profile happens while logging into the session (especially visually unpleasant if the greeter uses the same wallpaper as my user).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ubuntu 12.04**

A [wishlist bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/901015) has been filed and fixed in Ubuntu 12.04, so you will see a button to set a profile as system-wide default (per device).

1. Open the *Color* page of the *System Settings* (press <kbd>Super</kbd> and search for *Color*),
2. Select the profile that should be applied system-wide.
3. Click on the *Set for all users* button in the bottom left:

   [image]

After entering your password, the color profile should be default for this device for all users, including `lightdm`.

**Ubuntu 11.10**

Before above mentioned bug was resolved you were able to do this too, the function is just rather difficult to discover:

1. Open the *Color* page of the *System Settings* (press <kbd>Super</kbd> and search for *Color*),
2. Select the device which profile should be applied system-wide,
3. Hit the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key (or "context menu key") and select *Set for all users*:

   [image]

After entering your password, the color profile should be default for this device for all  users, including `lightdm`.